# Get current user for config.yml

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am working on a project where we would like to have sendmail send all emails to the currently logged in user. I know we can do this in the code, but it is a bit ugly.

What I would like to do is reference the currently logged in user in config_xxx.yml i.e

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address:  security.context.user
```

Now of course that doesn't work, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

Thanks for your help,
Q

Comment: Why do you say doing it in the code is ugly? This is definitely the way to go in your case!

Comment: We are moving it between 4 different environments, so we would like to use the config_xxx.yml files to define the behavior in each environment. I can do it in code with a case statement, but doing it in config_xxx.yml leaves me with cleaner code and a portable app.

Comment: How would you define behaviour in a config file? :) config file stores configuration, code has behaviour. Write a service to send e-mails and  pass it appropriate configuration options.

Comment: According to http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/email/dev_environment.html you can direct swiftmailer send all emails to a single address. I just want to set the delivery address value to the currently logged in user for our beta test environment.